# R won't load yaml.lessons

Tags: r, data-cleaning, swirl

Cant get dplyr lesson (yaml.lesson) to work in Swirl, keep getting this:

Error in yaml.load(readLines(con, warn = readLines.warn), error.label = error.label, :
(C:/Users/My Name/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/swirl/Courses/Getting_and_Cleaning_Data/Manipulating_Data_with_dplyr/lesson.yaml) Scanner error: while scanning a tag at line 205, column 9 did not find expected whitespace or line break at line 205, column 19

| Leaving swirl now. Type swirl() to resume.

Thank you from the bottom of my heart. None of these work arounds are making any sense to me. I appreciate the help

Rob

Comment: Try pasting the content of "lesson.yaml" in any online YAML-validator (e.g. https://yamlchecker.com/) to see what's going wrong in line 205.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.